# Grails: disable g:datePicker

Tags: grails, tags, datepicker

How does one disable g:datePicker when the page loads?

The code is supposed disable the datePicker when a variable (isCurrent) is true.

```
<g:if test="${!isCurrent}">
                    <g:datePicker name="endDate" precision="month" value="${projectInstance?.endDate}" years="${2005..2050}"/>
                </g:if>
                <g:else>
                    <g:datePicker name="endDate" precision="month" value="${projectInstance?.endDate}" years="${2005..2050}" disabled="disabled"/>
                </g:else>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't create the date picker in your <g:else>.  Just create a hidden input.  If you want it to look the same as a disabled date picker, you can build it without input elements so it will be display-only.

Answer (score 0):

`disabled="disabled"` is the attribute of select not datepicker. Datepicker won't pass along that attribute to your select tags. However, what you can do is to disable your selects using javascript. For example if you are using jQuery you can do something like this:

**note**: in my example, `isCurrent` is string change yours accordingly. Put this in the html body after the datepicker tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if ("${isCurrent}"=='true'){
       alert("${isCurrent}");
       $("#endDate_month").attr('disabled','disabled')
       $("#endDate_year").attr('disabled','disabled')               
    }
</script>
```

or just use the select tag directly.

Answer (score 0):

you can also computer wheater or not you want to disable the date picker in the backing controller and pass it into the date picker tag.

view.gsp

```
<g:datePicker disabled="${diabled}" .... />
```

controllerView.groovy

```
def view = {
disabled = true
if (isCurrent)
   disabled = false
[disabled, disabled]  
}
```

the javascript call above works nicely as well